# how to request with method post to asp.net web service from php and get response

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, post

```
POST /abc/abcServiceWSService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: abc.def.org
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://def.org/getActiveAbc"
```

it's web service sample

how to request with method post to asp.net web service from php and get response ?

Comment: What do you expect? That people can fantasize an SOAP Envelope? You got to have an example envelope for which we can see or maybe a type definition?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery Ajax to post this webservice and get response message like the example below:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/abc/abcServiceWSService.asmx",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: onSuccessFunction
        });
    });
    function onSuccessFunction(message){
//message contains your response :)
}
```

Don't forget to include jquery